# AngularJS interceptor only has rejection code -1

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
interceptorService.$inject = ['$q', 'config'];
function interceptorService($q, config){
    this.responseError = function (rejection) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(rejection));
        if (rejection.status === -1) {              
            //location.href = config.reloginPage;
        }
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    };
}
```

And as far as the alert is showing me object rejection, I can only see there status -1 (even if in firebug I see that service returned 500 error status).

How can I force interceptor to show proper error statuses?

---

**UPDATE:**

After researching, status -1 is set when there are no *CORS* headers in response from server. When `500 Internal server error` code was returned, standard way to add those headers was not executed since service threw exception. I've found way to add them by adding class implementing `ExceptionMapper`.

Right now I have another problem with -1 status:

- what if server is down? It won't return any response.
- what if service isn't up? Server should return `404 Not found response`.
- what if service will be timed out?

How can I add *CORS* headers to response if it's 404 error? How should I handle it?

My server is on WildFly, implementing Java 8.